# Cannot read property of undefined a props value

Tags: react-native, react-props

I'm trying to compare two value coming from a props, but one is undefined. When I console.log the undefined props like that: [image]

And I have this result:
[image]

How is it possible and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I  solve the problem adding - 1 in my for lign 1 and 2